# Can't set button's onclick callback to a function in a string

Tags: javascript, button, callback, onclick

I'm making an app that lets users upload stuff. I am trying to set the onclick callback of an upload button to a function by doing this inside one of my classes:

```js
this.uploadMusicButton.onclick = "upload('music' + this.frameNum)"; 

// ^ this code is inside of a custom class
// the code below is outside of any js class

function upload(purpose)
{
  alert("made it here");
  uploadPurpose = purpose;                 
  document.getElementById("openFile").click();
}
```

But when I try clicking the button, nothing happens. Can someone please help me?

Comment: `"upload('music' + this.frameNum)"` is a string, not a function.

Comment: You are adding a string to `onclick` property, not a function, if you want to execute the string, you'll need add it via `setAttribute("onclick", "upload('music' + this.frameNum)")` but that is a bad practice, use `addEventListener` instead